# onchange functions on boolean fields in odoo 8

Tags: python, xml, odoo

i would like to know how onchange function works with boolean and integer fields.
Suppose if one boolean field get changed to True, the value of respective integer should be changed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**@api.onchange**

This decorator will trigger the call to the decorated function if any of the fields specified in the decorator is changed in the form:

```
@api.onchange('fieldx')
def do_stuff(self):
   if self.fieldx == x:
       self.fieldy = 'toto'
```

In previous sample self corresponds to the record currently edited on the form. When in on_change context all work is done in the cache. So you can alter RecordSet inside your function without being worried about altering database. That’s the main difference with @api.depends

At function return, differences between the cache and the RecordSet will be returned to the form.

***View management***

One of the great improvement of the new API is that the onchange are automatically inserted into the form for you in a simple way. You do not have to worry about modifying views anymore.

***Warning and Domain***

To change domain or send a warning just return the usual dictionary. Be careful not to use @api.one in that case as it will mangle the dictionary (put it in a list, which is not supported by the web client).